# What's the difference between `Task` and `async` in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, async-await

So I have seen code like:

```
func doSomething() {
  async {
    let foo = await something()
  }
}
```

vs

```
func doSomething() {
  Task {
    await doSomething()
  }
}
```

There's also a modifier version of the Task:

```
TextView(...)
  .task {
    let foo = await something()
  }
```

I am wondering what's the difference between these and which one should I use?

Comment: `async` as you have shown was the original and was deprecated early in Beta 2 or 3 maybe? I don't remember the exact version `Task` is the "final" version

Comment: here is the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/taskgroup/3851242-async?changes=latest_major) some of the videos and lessons still show it but Xcode tells you to change to `Task`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`async { ... }`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/async(priority:operation:)-6nw1p) is deprecated. It has been replaced by `Task { ... }`, which uses [this initialiser](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/3856791-init) of `Task`.

`Task { ... }` runs an asynchronous operation as a top level task.

The [`.task`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/task(priority:_:)) *view modifier*, on the other hand, is a *view modifier*, and runs the asynchronous operation *when the view appears*. Importantly, this task has the same life time as the view. If the view gets removed, the task gets cancelled too.

Compare:

```
func foo() {
    Task {
        await doWork() // gets started when foo is called
    }
}
```

and

```
Text("Hello")
    .task {
        // gets started when "Hello" appears,
        // *not* when .task is called
        await doWork() 
    }
```

Comment: Here's [deprecated async {...}](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/async(priority:operation:)-6nw1p?changes=la) page.

Comment: @AndyJazz Thanks for finding that! Added to the answer.